# Firebase deployed react app not working. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have my app perfectly running in http://localhost:3000/ when I run my development server with `npm start`. However, when I `npm run build` and the `firebase deploy` the app, the app is not running and is throwing the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'.

Find my firebase.json:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to add this, in case something was catched with no success:

```
"headers": [
      {
        "source" : "/sw.js",
        "headers" : [
          {
            "key" : "Cache-Control",
            "value" : "no-store"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

And my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "marioplan",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "firebase": "^8.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.14.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I read somthing and made trials regarding '"homepage":' needed to be specified in the packaje.jason, as the `npm run build` throws:

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

Also I tried removing `npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint` predeploy command as I am not clear about what it does also with no different results.

Just in case anyone might wonder, I do check that the files are actually deployed in the firebase hosting console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not serving any JavaScript, but HTML and that's where the unexpected `<` comes from. I'd blame this one rewrite rule, which provides "limited" sense, as it will always serve `index.html`:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Comment: I removed that and it works. Many thanks. If you would be so kind to extend a little bit the explanation, I dont understand very well why before it did not work and now it does.

Comment: The glob pattern `**` matches any location (including requests for `*.js`) and will rewrite to `/index.html`. So `source` is the location being requested and `destination` will be the outcome. See [Glob pattern matching](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#glob_pattern_matching), in case you may require any other rewrite rules.

Comment: @MartinZeitler when I remove this, I get 404 on the files. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I also have the 404 on the other files after removing this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @removing this will not work, as it results in 404

Comment: @AshadNasim Whatever you may interpret into my answer, I've never wrote that - but only pointed out what is wrong. See the link for glob pattern matching and then learn how to do it.